# How to combine accuracy with certainty

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say someone predicts with 75% certainty that an event X will occur. However, you know from past experience that this person has an accuracy of 10%.

What's the appropriate way to combine the predictor's own certainty with your own objective accuracy rating of that person?

For example, could you simply multiply them together, `75% * 10% = 7.5%`? Since this is a boolean prediction, could you calculate the odds of the event not occurring by inverting it like `75% * 90% = 67.5%` or `25% * 90% = 22.5%`. Or should you completely ignore the predictor's certainty and use your own accuracy?

Is there a mathematically "proper" way to do this, or is combining these two numbers only acting as a heuristic?

Comment: What does it mean to say they predict with $75\%$ certainty?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  The fact that someone says "I believe $x$ with confidence $y$" has no mathematical meaning that I can think of.  If the person is right only $10\%$ of the time, then I'd say the best estimate was $10\%$.

Comment: What does it mean they have an accuracy of $10\%$?  Does that mean when they say something is $75\%$ likely to happen it is somewhere between $65\%$ and $85\%$?  Once you define it, there may be an answer.

Comment: @lulu, Literally what it says. "Bob told me he's 75% sure the Yankees are going to win."

Comment: Yes, but what does he usually say when he makes his (catastrophically inaccurate) predictions? If he always says $75\%$ then this is business as usual, and the answer should be $10\%$.  Otherwise...well, I don't suppose there is any basis for correlating Bob's lousy predictive powers with his self-cofidence.

Comment: @RossMillikan, By 10%, I mean if they made 10 predictions in the past of a boolean event, only 1 was correct in that their certainty was either > 50% that it would happen and it did, or < 50% that it would not happen and it did not.

Comment: But if they say it is $75\%$ to happen, like one of two coins coming up heats, you shouldn't say it is a failed prediction if both come up tails.  It was a correct prediction.  If they are only right $10\%$ of the time when they say something is more likely than not their judgement is poor, but you need a number of events to see that.  In normal life, people exaggerate how close things are to certain.

Answer (score 0):

In classical mechanics, you have certainty but not accuracy.

in quantum mechanics, you have accuracy but not certainty.

in probability, you have nothing.